# extract div tags inside div

Tags: php, arrays, html, preg-match

i want to extract div tags inside div ...

The post.php file:

```
<body>
<div class="home">

<div id="post_message_14674248">Content number 14674248</div>
<div id="post_message_14674255">Content number 14674255</div>
<div id="post_message_14674278">Content number 14674278</div>
<div id="post_message_14674279">Content number 14674279</div>
<div id="post_message_14674283">Content number 14674283</div>
<div id="post_message_14674290">Content number 14674290</div>
.
.
.
.
</div>
</body>
```

The extract.php file :

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents("post.php");
   $pattern = "/(<div id=\"post_message_)(.*)(<\/div>)/";
   preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
   print_r($matches);

?>
```

but it give me an empty array :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) )
```

and i want it like this:

```
Content number 14674248
Content number 14674255
Content number 14674278
Content number 14674279
Content number 14674283
Content number 14674290
```

any help ?

Comment: Everytime you use regexes to parse HTML, a baby seal horribly dies - use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile("post.php");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$filtered = $xpath->query("//div[@class='home']/div");

foreach($filtered as $one){
    echo $one->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. But, there could be an issue when using it against [malformed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/its-a-malformed-world.html) html.

Comment: It could be an issue for any script against malformed HTML ... also your solution does not cover the `class="home"`, his first line starts with `i want to extract div tags inside div`

Comment: great ...now if i want to extract the firs div only ?? what will i do ?

Comment: You drop the foreach and just: `echo $filtered->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Verify that [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) is working. If I run the following code I get results:

```
<?php 
$html = '<div class="home">

<div id="post_message_14674248">Content number 14674248</div>
<div id="post_message_14674255">Content number 14674255</div>
<div id="post_message_14674278">Content number 14674278</div>
<div id="post_message_14674279">Content number 14674279</div>
<div id="post_message_14674283">Content number 14674283</div>
<div id="post_message_14674290">Content number 14674290</div>
</div>
</body>';
   $pattern = "/(<div id=\"post_message_)(.*)(<\/div>)/";
   preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
   print_r($matches);

?>
```

You may also want to change the regex to something like the following:

```
$pattern = "/<div id=\"post_message_.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/";
```

Comment: or you could use file() and have each line of the code in an array